# How can I specify per flavor buildType sourceSets?

Tags: android, gradle

I've got 2 flavors of an app that each have their own google maps (v1) key for debug and release (meaning 4 keys total). So I'd like to know if I can specify sourceSets based on the buildType and productFlavor. Essentially, I'm wondering how I can achieve something like this:

```
src
├── debug
│   └── flavor1
│       └── res
│           └── values
│               └── gmaps_key.xml
├── release
│   └──flavor1
│       └── res
│           └── values
│               └── gmaps_key.xml
```

Where gradle will use the `src/<currentBuldType>/<currentProductFlavor>/*` as part of its sourceSet.

Essentially I want it so that if I run `gradle assembleFlavor1Debug` it will include everything under `src/main/*`, `src/flavor1/*`, and `src/debug/flavor1/*`.

My build.gradle is super simple:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }   

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }   
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 8

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName 'com.flavor1'
        }
        flavor2 {
            packageName 'com.flavor2'
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Or maybe a better approach to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Google Maps API integration you can check my gradle sample code here : https://github.com/shakalaca/learning_gradle_android/tree/master/07_tricks

Basically do a little trick in `android.applicationVariants.all` during the `mergeResources` phase, and place the API key in strings.xml under different flaver/buildtype combination folder.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because this is very similar to how I ended up doing things.

Answer (score 19):

I happened to come back to this because of a comment on my answer and realized that this answer is superfluous (still better than the accepted one which is even more so). For each productFlavor and buildType, combination and individual source sets already exist. i.e. `src/{buildType}`, `src/{productFlavor}` and `src/{productFlavor}{buildType}` are already available source folders.

So essentially, all that was needed for the OP was to put the resources in `src/flavor1Debug` which is equivalent to the `src/debug/flavor1` that the OP envisions.

**OLD ANSWER:**
I've done something similar with `buildConfig` but hopefully it should work with `sourceSets`.

Basically, you define the common stuff at the `productFlavors` level in a variable and keep adding things as you move down.

```
productFlavors {
        def common = 'src/main'

        flavor1 {
            def flavor = 'src/main/flavor1'
            buildTypes {
                debug {
                    sourceSets {
                        res.srcDirs = [ common + ',' + flavor + ',' + 'src/main/debug'
                    }
                }

                release {
                    sourceSets {
                        res.srcDirs = [ common + ',' + flavor + ',' + 'src/main/release'
                    }

            }
        }
}
```

I haven't tested this. I think you might need to use `android.sourceSets` instead of just `sourceSets`.

I've also needed to define separate resources for the `productFlavors` so I used a separate statement late in the build file. Like so:

```
android.sourceSets.flavor1 {
    res.srcDirs = ['flavor_resources/flavor1/res']
}
```

You should just be able to use `android.sourceSets.flavor1.debug` instead if you need to.

Also note that according to the Android Gradle [user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks), using `srcDir` adds the directory to the default sources and `srcDirs` replaces them.

Comment: How would I do this dynamically? I have sourceSets.whenObjectAdded { sourceSet -> sourceSet.java.srcDirs = "someDir"} and then the source sets defined per flavor like this: sourceSets { flavor1{} flavor2{}}. I want to do something like: sourceSet.debug.java.srcDirs = "someDir" for each product flavor and per buildType.

Comment: I edited the answer, do you still need something more custom?

Comment: Hy @saad farooq I'm aware of the solution that was edited (thank you for posting it anyways!), however my product flavors are complex and reuse resources. I might need to rethink what im doing, but the dynamic solution for me would be nicer, since I have 12 product flavors and I don't want to create additional folders like this flavor1Release, flavor1Debug, flavor1DebugFull. This would lead to a permutaion of too many folders, it's time consuming to maintain it. I posted a question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589641/gradle-sourcesets-by-productflavor-and-buildtype