# In Multi Flavour app, how to avoid duplicate resources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

If I have 3 flavors flavor1, flavor2 and flavour3, each flavor has Dev,Pat and Prod "sub-flavours" versions which different parameters , but each main flavor have different resources.

So I have now 9 different flavors, but  only 3 different resource folders). I would like the same "sub-flavors" to use the same resources.

How can I do that? I have seen in the documentation about the flavorDimensions but not sure how to configure the resource folder.

At the moment I am using something like

```
sourceSets {

   flavor1_dev{
            res.srcDir  'src/flavor1/res'
        }

   flavor1_prod{
            res.srcDir  'src/flavor1/res'
        }

   flavor2_dev{
            res.srcDir  'src/flavor2/res'
        }

   flavor2_prod{
            res.srcDir  'src/flavor2/res'
        }

}
```

Comment: Yeah it works but I would like to know how to use the flavorDimensions , or if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: You can exclude resources from different flavor builds, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263567/how-to-exclude-res-folder-from-gradle-build-flavours/45581826#45581826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Gradle flavours eg. `flavor1`, `flavor2` etc, as well as Build Types like `dev`, `prod` etc.

See the example from: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

For example:

`android.sourceSets.flavor1Debug`
Location src/flavor1Debug/

`android.sourceSets.flavor1Release`
Location src/flavor1Release/

`android.sourceSets.flavor2Debug`
Location src/flavor2Debug/

`android.sourceSets.flavor2Release`
Location src/flavor2Release/

Also, this question is very similar [How can I specify per flavor buildType sourceSets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119342/how-can-i-specify-per-flavor-buildtype-sourcesets)

Comment: Any idea on how to do it with flavorDimension ? http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants

Answer (score -2):

Just put common resources in the main/res. All the resources in the main/res will be overridden by the flavour.
For example if you want to override string resources add,

main string file: /src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Main</string>
    <string name="app_name_full">Main app</string>
    <string name="app_email">main@abc.com</string>
    <string name="app_phone">123</string>
    <string name="app_website">www.abc.com</string>
</resources>
```

and flavour string file: /src/flavor1/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Flavour App Name</string>
</resources>
```

Only app_name is going to changed in the flavour and other resources like app_full_name is still accessible in all flavours.

Comment: You cannot use main and expect it to be overridden. This will not work. Main should be used for "in everything", else it needs to be separated.

Comment: @StarWind has a point here this will fail at compile time with "duplicate resources"