# Gradle SourceSets by productFlavor and buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-type

**EDIT** flavors and paths:

Currently I have:

```
sourceSets.whenObjectAdded { 
    sourceSet -> 
    def sourceData = rootProject.ext[sourceSet.name]
    sourceSet.java.srcDirs = sourceData.javaDirRelease
}
```

The rootProject.ext is a file where all the productFlavor specific configuration is defined like this:

```
ext{
    flavor1 = [
        javaDirRelease : ['src/pathToJavaReleaseFiles']
        javaDirDebug : ['src/pathToJavaDebugFiles']
    ]
}
```

In the main build.gradle I also do: `apply from: 'variants.gradle'` which contains the above ext{} object.

The sourceSets are defined as such:

```
sourceSets {
   flavor1{}
}
```

This works but I want to do add a sourceSet specific to productFlavor and the buildType like this:

```
sourceSet.debug.java.srcDirs = 'src/pathToJavaDebugFiles'
```

Which could be defined for each product flavor and per buildType, but this doesn't work when I try to add it dynamically.

What works for me is this (thanks to this answer [How can I specify per flavor buildType sourceSets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119342/how-can-i-specify-per-flavor-buildtype-sourcesets)):

```
sourceSets {
    flavor1{
        def flavorData = rootProject.ext['flavor1']
        release {
            java.srcDirs = flavorData.javaDirRelease
        }
        debug {
            java.srcDirs = flavorData.javaDirDebug
        }
    }
}
```

However I would really like this to be added dynamically, so I can still preserve my configuration file intact. My build configuration is quite complex and not as simple as described here, therefore I don't need a suggestion to put the source files into a folder src/flavor1Debug because this resources are used from other productFlavors also, so this won't work.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you want here... you say `I want to do add a sourceSet` but the code snippet is setting java source dirs on an existing sourceSet? Also, you have an apply from a gradle file; what's in `variants.gradle`? Is that where you define ext {} object? Then where does `javaDirRelease` come from?

Comment: I edited the answer a bit, so you have a better understanding of the variants.gradle, that file just contains the paths of source directories nothing else. The "add to sourceSet" was a semantic misunderstanding, I meant "set a sourceSet". The variants.gradle contain the ext{} object yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand. I will say first off once again that this is not a great setup and you should really look to move towards a more standard setup.

So for the solution, in order to read flavor sources dynamically, I recommend moving your ext structure to something like this:

```
ext {
    sources = [
        flavor1Debug : ['src/pathToJavaReleaseFiles']
        flavor1Release : ['src/pathToJavaDebugFiles']
    ]
}
```

This lets you read the source paths and iterate over keys and values in `project.ext.sources`.

Then you can find the variant by name and add sources from the array.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def extraSources = project.ext.sources.get(variant.name)
        if (extraSources != null) {
            def extraSourceFiles = extraSources.collect { project.file(it) }
            def sourceSet = variant.sourceSets.find { it.name == variant.name }
            sourceSet.java.srcDir extraSourceFiles
            def dummyTask = project.task("register${variant.name}ExtraSourcesTask")
            variant.registerJavaGeneratingTask(dummyTask, extraSourceFiles)
        }
    }
```

The annoyance with doing this at the variant level is that you have to register the extra sources since the variant object at this point has already collected the sources from the source set and product flavors. However, I think this is probably the least invasive way to do this dynamically.

Comment: Hey @saadfarooq, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have e.g 3 flavors, and some additional sources e.g NotificationMechanism, AdLibraries. Now only 2nd and 3rd flavor need to include NotificationMechanism and the 1st flavor needs both NotificationMechanism and AdLibraries. In my case I have 12 flavors and additional sources, as you may presume the complexity of the setup is higher. I don't have a general idea on how to change the setup in this way.

Comment: All you need to do is change you ext gradle file a bit... if you can't do that you're stuck with what you have.

Comment: @SaadFarooq Thanks for posting this, it's very useful. In my project however, * *applicationVariants* is empty, even though I have several flavors and build types. I'm printing it to the log after initializing all flavors and build types. Do you know why it could be empty?

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn How are printing it out? You would have to do in `project.afterEvaluate` for it to work.